# Problems with interpolating using impute.interp in Julia

Tags: julia, linear-interpolation

I have a problem with interpolating. In the data is everything okay using this code, exept this interval when interpolating from datapoint 40903 and 40997 with the data Lat[40903] = 12.4461 and Lat[40997] = 12.4460. The datapoints in between is missing and have to be interpolated to be useful. Is it possible somehow? The results of interpolating is giving me -0.0 for most of the needed values.

```
using CSV
using DataFrames
using Impute

data = CSV.read("data.csv", delim=",", header=5, datarow=6, silencewarnings=true)
Lat = Impute.interp(data[:,8]) |> Impute.locf() |> Impute.nocb()
```

Comment: This is quite hard to answer as it is not a minimal working example - you are referring to `data` which is undefined, and it is unclear which package you are using (probably Impute.jl, but it's good practice to make this explicit in your example).

Answer (score 0):

If you know the exact bounds of a section with missing values, and can use linear interpolation to fill, you should be able to generate a Range object for each column with missing values from the top and bottom of that section's values and the number of points in that section.  For example, if the bottom X in the column is 1.5 and the top X is 1.3 and the number of missing values between is 5,

```
LinRange(1.5, 1.3, 5 + 2)[2:6]
```

will give the values you need. Impute.jl should do this as well.